# How to one-step-add current movie playing in Media Player Classic to the favorites list?

Tags: windows-7, favorites, media-player-classic

How to one-step-add current movie playing in Media Player Classic to the favorites list? I can go to favorites with the mouse and click to add but there are several steps. Is there some key I can assign? I looked in the shortcut keys list but could not find anything to add to favorites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> followed by two times <kbd>a</kbd> seems to be the shortest and fastest way to me.
*(After pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> some letters in Menu gets underlined, use them for more such shortcuts)*

[image]

**Alternative:**
You can use following [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) script to automate with just one Hotkey press.
Install [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) and save following script as `.ahk` file and run it.
Then you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to adds it to favourites (no other keypress needed).

> !d::Send !aa{Enter}

Comment: This is a great workaround, I can program my mouse to do it even. Thanks.